# Circular / arc spine in custom matplotlib Axes class

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I am trying to build a class to create a radialplot, also known as
Galbraith plot (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galbraith_plot).
It's essentially a cartesian plot of standardised estimates vs associated errors. The estimates values are represented by the slope of the line that goes through the origin.

here is what it looks like.

[image]

Now I want reproduce that with matplotlib so I thought I would build a
class that inherits from `Axes`...
So far so good...

Now I am wondering what to do with the right `spine`. 
I could obviously plot a line and create ticks manually in the plotting area but I would rather do it properly and use the matplotlib machinery...

I saw that there are options to create a circular spine, or even arc spine.
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/spines_api.html

Looking at the spine documentation a Spine object requires, an axes, a type and a path... I am not sure what to do with that.
If I you give a path to the Spine class, what's the point of having the `arc_spine` or `circular_spine` method...

I thought I could do something like this (self refers to an Axis instance):

```
    x, y = self.zscale_coordinates()
    verts = list(zip(x,y))
    codes = [Path.LINETO for i in range(len(verts))]
    codes[0] = Path.MOVETO
    spine = Spine(self, "right", Path(verts, codes))
    self.spines["right"] = spine
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Maybe someone has already done this? I found some R or Java packages but nothing with matplotlib and I would like to include it in some python code.

Thanks!